Can someone explain the difference of "note" vs "take note"? Thanks
Can someone explain the difference of "note" vs "take note"? Both have the meaning of "paying special attention". Is the "special attention" the same with both words? And does "note (v)" have other meaning as well?". Thanks

First, please look both words up in a dictionary, then edit to focus on whatever questions you have afterwards. "Note" does have other meanings. Also, when used with an object, "take note" will usually need "of" added.

Sorry for not making the question clearer. What I mean the difference between the two words here are the difference of the "pay attention" meaning. Like is there a specific context where the "pay attention" of one word can only be used but not the other?

Compare the two links provided by Andy. Instructors had noted that he did not perform well - they had noticed it, become aware of the fact. When you take note of something it's a bit stronger - you either write yourself a reminder or make a conscious decision to do something about it.
